# iPhone, creating a texture using an array

Tags: iphone, textures

I would like to copy an array of pixel data (colors) into a texture. Please could someone point me in the right direction? I have looked on google but all of the tutorials are for OpenGL, rather than OpenGL ES. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s about the same as in OpenGL:

1. create the texture object in OpenGL ES:
   `glGenTextures(1, &textureID);`
2. bind the texture object:
   `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);`
3. upload texture data (from your c array):
   `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,                     GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixeldata);`

After that you can applay the texture to your geometry. Of course, the texture has to have the right dimensions (power of 2, square), pixel format and so on.